# Binding button in Kivy makes funciton run when the program is run

Tags: python, kivy

Im using

```
Button:
   on_press: app.test()
```

But whenever I run the program instead of showing a button the function I've binded it to just runs automatically. Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

you should probably do

```
root.test()
```

not

```
app.test()
```

Comment: unless you overrided the root in which case should be correct